# Comparar array de objetos e deletar repetidos

Tags: javascript, array, node.js, objetos

Preciso fazer um método onde eu recebo do frontend um array de objetos, e comparo com o array de objetos q tenho no banco, então eu realizo a consulta no banco que é data1 e data 2 é o que vem do frontend, preciso confererir se no data1 existe o id do data2 e se existir apagar a posição para retornar para o fronte o que ele não mandou

```
const data1 = [
        { id: 1, nome: 'fulano' },
        { id: 2, nome: 'ciclano' },
      ];

const data2 = [
        { id: 1, nome: 'fulano' },
        { id: 3, nome: 'joao' },
      ];
```

O que preciso fazer é verificar se no array data1 existe um objeto com ID igual do array data2 e se houver remova do data1 id e nome.
o que eu ja tentei é:

```
const filtered = data1.filter(item => data2.filter(item1 => item1.d === data.id).pop());
```

o retorno esperado é esse:

```
const dataFiltered = [
        { id: 2, nome: 'ciclano' },
        { id: 3, nome: 'joao' },
      ];
```

Comment: O código que você _tentou_ nem chega a ser executado. O que deveria ser `data`? É um _binding_ indefinido que está completamente descontextualizado ali.

Comment: são dados q vem do banco, eu estou fazendo um app de conferencia, então o front manda um array de objetos e eu preciso comparar esse array com o q tenho no banco e retornar pro usuario apenas o ele n conferiu sabe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, boa tarde!
Pelo oque entendi, você gostaria de "mapear" uma array, verificar os elementos nela, e se o elemento da array1 for igual o elemento da array2, você remove ele.

```
const data1 = [
  { id: 1, nome: 'fulano' },
  { id: 2, nome: 'ciclano' }
];

const data2 = [
  { id: 1, nome: 'fulano' },
  { id: 3, nome: 'joao' }
];

const dataFiltered = [];

for(var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++){
  if(data1[i].id != data2[i].id){
      dataFiltered.push(data1[i]);
      dataFiltered.push(data2[i]);
  }
};

console.log(dataFiltered);//[ { id: 2, nome: 'ciclano' }, { id: 3, nome: 'joao' } ]
```

Fiz esse código e espero ter ajudado!

OBS: esse código só funcionara corretamente se as arrays estiverem com o mesmo "tamanho"